# Waiting for a backend process response using Spring Boot, Kafka and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.4, Kafka and React as a frontend UI. I have a user registration process from the UI which requires a backend process and it's data before the registration is complete.

The flow is like this:

1. The frontend UI makes a request to an API which returns a token and puts a message on to a request Kafka queue
2. The message is processed by a backend process (which takes approximately 1 minute)
3. When the process is finished, a message with the token and data is written to a reply Kafka queue which indicates the process is complete

What I want is the frontend UI to make the initial API request which returns immediately, show a loading screen and display a ready message when the registration process is complete.

I have thought of a couple of options:

1. Attach a KafkaListener to the reply queue. Once the reply message appears, store the response and token in a datastore (e.g. Redis). Provide an API to the UI which checks the datastore for the token. The UI will poll this API every 10 seconds. If the response is not available after 2 mins, the user will be asked to check back later.
2. Use WebSockets with React. I've not used WebSockets before but the only thing I'm unsure of is if I have multiple instances of the registration microservice, will this cause any issues with client/api communication.

Any recommendations or any other options on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Attach a KafkaListener to the reply queue. Once the reply message appears, store the response and token in a datastore (e.g. Redis). Provide an API to the UI which checks the datastore for the token. The UI will poll this API every 10 seconds. If the response is not available after 2 mins, the user will be asked to check back later.

This will work. I would use the built in RocksDB for storage though, just for simplicity. Below is the documentation for exposing a state store to be queryable outside of kafka streams.

https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

> 2. Use WebSockets with React. I've not used WebSockets before but the only thing I'm unsure of is if I have multiple instances of the registration microservice, will this cause any issues with client/api communication.

It can potentially cause issues. It depends on the implementation of the registration service. You won't know which instance of the registration service a client will establish a connection with. For instance session needs to be managed in a external datasource like Redis or you would have to use a laod balancer that supports sticky sessions (a bit of an archaic solution).

Comment: Great thanks for your help. I thought websockets looked promising but I want to keep the architecture stateless as much as I can.